# Why does <ul> with display:inline does not bring list items with the document flow as <ul> with display:inline-block does

Tags: css, user-interface, inline, display

This below image is the screen shot for my code which has `<ul> display:inline` and I did not change `<li>` display which is block by default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The elements with *display:inline-block* are like *display:inline elements*. *display:inline-block* can have a **width** and a **height** while *display:inline* doesn't. That means that you can use an inline-block element as a block while flowing it within text or other elements.

Comment: Plus 1 for even trying to answer this question, you're braver than I am

Comment: Thanks!
I answer because I wanted him to have more options for his problem. I hope I'm able to help him.